Scroll to reveal content?
I’d like to create a div where the content div is hidden in its initial state. The content div would be 'revealed' from the bottom of the parent div as the user scrolls down the page. I'd also like to use an image (think mountains) that would sit at the bottom of the parent div...giving the allusion of the content coming from up behind the mountain.
Initial state:

Scrolling:


It’s not completely clear what you are trying to achieve. Please edit your post to include some screenshots and/or diagrams/sketches/mockups of your actual results versus your desired results. Adding a minimal reproducible example as a stack snippet to your post will also help us answer your question, and will also help your question stay relevant to others in the future, long after your link has rotted away.

@BrettDonald...you're absolutely right. Thank you for your insight. I've updated the description and provided some low-fi visuals. I hope that helps. Thanks!

There are many library provides this functionality. For react framer motion would be best and gsap supports CDN so it can be used with anything.

In this example the mountains are a sticky pseudoelement: click on "full page" to see the result


body {
   font: 1.2rem/1.6 system-ui;
   margin: 0;
   
   img {
      inline-size: 100%;
      max-block-size: 100%;
      object-fit: cover; 
   }   
}

#sect-1 {
   block-size: 70dvb;
}

#sect-2 {
   padding-inline: calc(50vw - 24rem);
}


div::after {
   content: "";
   position: sticky;
   display: block;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: 1;
   inline-size: 100%;
   block-size: max(28dvb, 20vw);
   background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 2000 400'><path d='M0 400 L0 250 L400 0 L1000 100 L1600 0 L2000 250 L2000 400' fill='red'/></svg>") 0 100% no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% auto;
}
<main>
   <div> 
      <section id="sect-1">
         <img src="https://placehold.co/1000x640/3FA9F5/111111?text=Section+1" />
      </section>
      <section id="sect-2">

         <h2>Section 2</h2>

         <p>Cat ipsum dolor sit amet, laboris sit. Sed. Eu quasi omnis or autem yet nulla. Consectetur. Reprehenderit duis sunt so cupidatat yet molestiae est. Veniam omnis, veritatis for laboris ut magnam. Dolorem elit qui for voluptatem so si explicabo. Aut dicta yet ullamco so anim. Eu doloremque for dolorem, so reprehenderit mollit and perspiciatis. Ipsa exercitationem. Aute molestiae. Velit sed, totam. Unde quia officia. Magni numquam for irure yet ipsa yet perspiciatis or et but adipisci. Dolor nulla yet cillum in nemo. Inventore. Quo ratione aliquid for ipsum yet adipisicing. Dolores illum and elit. Velitesse commodi but elit so minim id so non eaque. Vitae ipsam, dolor odit officia yet iure.</p>
         <p>Molestiae cillum so aliquam for suscipit and si so eos. Odit illo magnam for unde and sequi. Amet nequeporro or autem, magni aperiam. Commodi. Quasi illo id or accusantium. Proident nostrum amet, do nesciunt.</p>
         <p>Natus ipsam consequuntur. Sed do modi officia but dolore yet quisquam dolores. Ab quae so ipsa cillum. Modi architecto eiusmod eos, or ea, do. Esse in so quaerat or vel. Veritatis est ipsa so in. Culpa eu. Amet iste iure enim or consectetur. Adipisicing fugiat. Eiusmod nihil. Eos. Dicta. Ullam. Id. Sint officia, consequatur and beatae, for eum et and excepteur. Adipisci ut so elit or voluptate, eum, for unde aliquam. Non. Aute nihil consequuntur sed but quam ipsum. Ratione ex but fugit. Laborum labore. Aliquip. Corporis nostrum nulla and quia for esse yet dolores yet vel. Inventore magnam so veritatis yet si qui but perspiciatis, enim. Accusantium nihil. Consectetur sit ut deserunt magnam ad mollit.Unde rem beatae laborum nesciunt but quasi. Non numquam for officia, yet consequat veritatis ab, or suscipit. Ipsum quaerat for id corporis. Aliquip ullamco, doloremque duis quia so ratione but vel. Eiusmod anim and quaerat. Est. Corporis incididunt and quasi molestiae. Aliquip veniam ratione. Architecto dolor but quia aperiam yet iure incididunt. Aliquip elit yet ab dolores so si quasi and ea. Mollit ut, for nisi so quis. Iure consequatur yet culpa or beatae, yet ab dolor. Aliquid exercitation quae ad or voluptate velit. Irure esse quia, occaecat. Aliquam. Proident sequi minima, and eum but laboriosam fugiat, or aliquip. Laboris consequatur omnis aut. Ut labore or minima molestiae. Ea ut. Laboriosam eaque aliquam.</p>
         <p>Fugiat in so numquam and laudantium ratione. Explicabo minim. Eum minim in or iste. Suscipit. Magni ex yet eiusmod inventore or eiusmod so accusantium and anim. Quasi dolore quisquam aliquam for laboriosam totam. Elit sed modi but accusantium yet consequat sequi or exercitationem. Perspiciatis velitesse for sunt so dolorem est. Sunt laboris commodi aspernatur. Natus ullam and accusantium. Molestiae. Do aut or perspiciatis eiusmod and proident or eius and quam. Tempor. Voluptas iure molestiae so deserunt cupidatat and sed. Architecto do yet dolores yet ullam for eaque for nesciunt do. Exercitation labore illum so aliquid for tempora. Molestiae minima yet est for eiusmod. Exercitation excepteur inventore laudantium excepteur.</p>
         <p>Ipsum eos sint lorem aut, but veritatis. Eiusmod. Anim ex sed. Sit. Magna veniam dolor for iure. Eaque accusantium. Perspiciatis quisquam or ab voluptate, veniam. Autem explicabo tempora, and irure and cillum sint. Voluptate minima reprehenderit amet. Minima minima and occaecat for quae quia, or beatae amet. Adipisicing excepteur. Illo. Ullamco si or odit or inventore for tempora consequatur eos. Ratione proident molestiae duis yet dolores, but odit, irure. Accusantium consequat yet quasi excepteur for aliquid yet nulla so aperiam. Magnam cupidatat but ipsa but eu yet explicabo for ipsam so minim. Cillum cupidatat magna. Ullamco laudantium si but lorem, and sequi. Voluptatem magnam, or enim eius. Eius voluptate iste magni, yet irure modi. Natus odit yet elit. Amet veritatis adipisci, est but illo labore for nesciunt. Inventore nostrud but magnam aspernatur for rem. Amet labore yet nesciunt and nostrum. Dolores culpa quia, so exercitation. Cillum aperiam numquam for exercitationem. Id. Minim. Adipisicing ipsam laboris. Reprehenderit aliquam for pariatur enim yet minim but quasi. In veritatis laboris yet quis inventore but consequuntur. Minima exercitation dicta eiusmod for sit but ullamco. Occaecat veritatis but omnis, veritatis but fugit. Magnam exercitationem but eos eius but exercitationem and qui and enim. Labore vitae, but lorem adipisicing for eos and dolor. Eius vitae. Vitae eiusmod. Labore explicabo but vitae or laboriosam in for ex, yet elit. Beatae consectetur, yet explicabo so ut so minim eos. Irure lorem aliquip, error for quasi. Ex enim so beatae iure. Id dicta so iste. Nostrud laboris or nemo veniam nostrud, eiusmod nostrum. Nihil eu, dolor lorem qui and sunt.</p>
      </section>
  </div>
   
  <section>
     <img src="https://placehold.co/1000x640/3FA9F5/111111?text=Section+3" />
   </section>
</main>




THANK YOU Fabrizio...this nailed it. I've learned so much from dissecting your code. Thank you for teaching me!
